# RocksDB tuning parameters for write-only usage to reduce memory

Tags: rocksdb

I'm using RocksDB in a process only for persisting data. I don't need to read. Unfortunately the memory usage is skyrocketing and I want to stop this using the options.

I'm currently using these options:

```
rocksdb::Options options;
options.compression = rocksdb::CompressionType::kZSTD;
options.create_if_missing = true;
options.create_missing_column_families = true;
options.write_buffer_size = 512000;
```

My understanding is the last parameter should stop memory growing because i've reduced the size of the buffers before they are flushed. However, memory is still growing.

Are there any additional parameters I can use to reduce memory for write-only usage?

Answer (score 0):

If there're only write, you can also disable block cache:
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/fd2079938d784babcea908c6c82aeb8b3afa42af/include/rocksdb/table.h#L232-L235

memory growth could also because the number of column families, number of SSTables. If possible, you can also just write SST by yourself and then ingest to rocksdb, which can reduce all the overhead on the write path: http://rocksdb.org/blog/2017/02/17/bulkoad-ingest-sst-file.html